# What exactly am I supposed to do with "module.exports = 'html_template_content'" on webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-html-loader, raw-loader

So I want to do a very simple task using webpack.

I have a few static HTML templates like e.g.

test.html

```
<div><span>template content</span></div>
```

and all I want to do is return the string inside the template
e.g

```
require("raw!./test.html")
```

with should return a string like:

```
"<div><span>template content</span></div>"
```

but instead, it returns the following string

```
"modules.exports = <div><span>template content</span></div>"
```

I have tried several modules, like the raw-loader and html-loader.
and they both behave the same way.So I took a look at the source code, just to find out that its SUPPOSED to behave this way.

[image: raw module source code]

> so what exactly am I expected to do with this, if I just want the raw
>   HTML?  is it a bad practice just to remove the prepended
>   "module.exports =" string? from the bundle
>   edit: removing the 'modules.export =' part results in the bundle returning nothing :/

my config

```
module.exports =
{
    module:
    {
        loaders:
            [
                { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw-loader" }
            ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show your webpack config? Returning a `module.exports` presumably is an internal webpack thing - you should be getting a raw string back

Comment: I posted the config above

Answer (score 12):

The solution is to require your file without specifying any additional loader, as this is already specified in the webpack config

```
const test = require('./test.html')
```

Explanation: With your current code, you are applying the `raw` loader twice to your file. When you specify a loader chain in your configuration:

```
loaders:
    [
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw-loader" }
    ]
```

... you are already telling webpack to add this loader to the loader chain every time you require a file matching the `test` condition (here, every html file)

Therefore, when you write this

```
const test = require('raw!./test.html')
```

... it is actually equivalent to this

```
const test = require('raw!raw!./test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out I think. You need to resolve the path name using `require.resolve(./test.html)` https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_require

Answer (score -3):

When you write `require('./test.html')` it means that you simply run the code returned by the loaders chain. The result is exported in this code as `module.exports`. To use this result you need to assign your require statement to variable:

```
var htmlString = require('raw!./test.html');
//htmlString === "<div><span>template content</span></div>"
```

Remember that any loader in Webpack returns JS code - not HTML, not CSS. You can **use** this code to get HTML, CSS and whatever.

Comment: oops it was a typo in the OP, I'm already using require('raw!./test.html'), and it returns the same string